# Unable to trigger firebase cloud messaging using php

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What I need to do is that, I will trigger this script from my android app and the device owner will receive a notification.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $db_name = "testdb";
  $mysql_username = "root";
  $mysql_password = "";
  $server_name = "localhost";

  function send_notification ($tokens , $message)
  {
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$fields = array(
                'registration_ids' => $tokens,
                'data' => $message
                );
$headers = array(
                'Authorization:key = AIzaSyBAYIZohaZPXBEGqktPh8YEfMlmuYnuCOk',
                'Content-Type: application/json'
                );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result == FALSE)
{
    die('Curl.failed: '.curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
  }

$conn = mysqli_connect    
                  ($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);
$sql = "select `token` from `user_token`;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$token = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $token[] = $row["token"];
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
$message = array('message' => "FCM MESSAGE");
$message_status = send_notification($token , $message);
echo $message_status;


   ?>
```

I have read a lots of blogs, stackoverflows but no positive result.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP Code is working fine. Actually you are sending `data` field only in `$fields` object. Please check console once again for FCM data. So, You have to manually build `Notification` object.

But, If you want default notification to notification panel, please modify your `$fileds` object as below and run.

```
$notificationObj = array(
                'title' => 'FCM',
                'body' => 'MESSAGE'
);
$fields = array(
                'registration_ids' => $tokens,
                'data' => $message,
                'notification' => $notificationObj 
                );
```